# SAAJ include client certificate

Tags: java, server-side, jaas, sslsocketfactory

I want to call web service over https and i need to include client certificate. I am doing that with SAAJ

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
conn = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
URL endpoint = new URL(urlEndPoint);
SOAPMessage response = conn.call(msg, endpoint);
```

but how to include client certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

I create

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = csm.getKeyManagerFactory();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = csm.getTrustManagerFactory();

SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().useProtocol("SSL").build();

sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
```

And then i setDefaultSSLSocketFactory

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: not sure where exactly are you adding the client certificate here